# Why are slicing with regex.lastIndex and with string's length different?

Tags: javascript, regex, slice

Here I match a string with a regex, then slicing it in 2 different ways:

```js
const string = 'hi hi'
const word = 'hi'
const regex = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    console.log(match.index, regex.lastIndex)
    console.log('slice with regex.lastIndex:', string.slice(match.index, regex.lastIndex))
    console.log('slice with string\'s length:', string.slice(match.index, word.length))
}
```

The result:

```
0 2
slice with regex.lastIndex: hi
slice with string's length: hi
3 5
slice with regex.lastIndex: hi
slice with string's length:
```

Why does the second time the slice not work?

Answer (score -2):

I miss to add `match.index`

```js
console.log('slice with string\'s length:', string.slice(match.index, match.index + word.length))
```